# Get the id from json file with twiiter typehead JQuery plugin

Tags: jquery, html, json, twitter-bootstrap, autocomplete

I have a simple textbox with auto-complete function which I've managed to achieve through [this plugin](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/doc/jquery_typeahead.md).
Everything works fine, however I'd like to retrieve the id related to the selected item from the json file to be able to perform updates on the database.

The json object looks like this:

```
[{"id":1,"name":"John Smith"},{"id":2,"name":"Mary Brown"},{"id":3,"name":"Joe April"}]
```

[Here's a working example](http://plnkr.co/edit/1AVgvy32WRfLcLNPiyqu?p=preview) without the id retrieval feature which is what I'm trying to figure out.

I know I could get the selected name and perform a new search looping through the json object to match the string and get the id but I'm wondering if there is a better solution to tie both name and id together as a dataset and easily get the selected id without having to loop through the dataset every time a new name is selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$("#prefetch .typeahead").typeahead(null, {
  name: "customers",
  displayKey: "name",
  source: customers.ttAdapter()
}).on("typeahead:selected", function(event, suggestion, data) {
  console.log(suggestion, suggestion.id);
});
```

See [jQuery#typeahead - Custom Events](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/doc/jquery_typeahead.md#user-content-custom-events) at

> `typeahead:selected` – Triggered when a suggestion from the dropdown
>   menu is selected. The event handler will be invoked with 3 arguments:
>   the jQuery event object, **the suggestion object**, and the name of the
>   dataset the suggestion belongs to.

plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/aK76DueDdivZMdhxwusA?p=preview

Comment: Ok, that partially works, but did point me out on the right direction though. It looks a bit like magic to me. Where does "data" is coming from? I'm asking because I have to retrieve the id on the "select" event and not as I type, otherwise it will only pick the last id whilst typing and not the selected one.